# Change data in textbox according a DB result VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I've designed a form in VB.net based on ODBC connection.

My user need to insert a product number in textbox1 and the description pulled from the DB is automatically shown in textbox2 after the user presses the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

After seeking on the net, I wrote something that doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Product_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Product.TextChanged
    Dim P, SQL As String
    Dim cn As OdbcConnection
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand

    P = Product.Text

    If P = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        cn = New OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; Server=*****; uid=*****;pwd=*****")
        SQL = "select part_long_name from dbtrans.parts where part_code='" & P & "'"
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(SQL)
        Description.Text = cmd.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run the form, I receive this output

[image]

Comment: Curious. What DB are you using that requires ODBC. No .net provider?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To perform an **Enter** `Keypress` Event. Try this:

1) Declare connection variables somewhere in the top of your form.

```
Dim Str As String = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; Server=*****; uid=*****;pwd=*****"
Dim con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(Str)
Dim CMD As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
```

2) Add Your `KeyPress` Event to your `TextBox` Control

```
Private Sub Product_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Product.KeyPress
   Select Case e.KeyChar
       Case ChrW(Keys.Enter) 'This when End-User presses Enter Key
        P = Product.Text
        If P = "" Then
           Exit Sub
        Else
           CMD = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("select part_long_name from dbtrans.parts where part_code='" & P & "'", con)
          If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
            con.Open()
            Description.Text = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)
            con.Close()
          End If
        End If
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Its work good!!
just one correct 
"Private Sub Product_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Product.KeyPress"
THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, that typo, you are right, it should be KeyPressEventArgs

Comment: I used to have a Form level connection but that is really frowned upon. A connection object needs to be disposed not just closed. A Using block will take care of that for you. It can be very bad to concatenate strings for Sql statements. Use parameters. Why a Select Case when there is only one case?

Comment: With regards select case, that was an example if you want to implement more than KeyPress action. For select statement, I would have done it inside a class, and call it within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Using` for database objects.
You have to use parameters instead of [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).
You have to link your Command to the Connection object you have created.
Finally, you have to actually execute your command instead of just creating it.

```
Using cn = New OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; Server=*****; uid=*****;pwd=*****")
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd = New OdbcCommand("select part_long_name from dbtrans.parts where part_code=?", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Nothing, OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = P

        Description.Text = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)
    End Using
End Using
```